# Question about positive recurrence vs null recurrence

Tags: probability, markov-chains

While reading some lecture notes I read the following statement about recurrent state $i$ and its mean return time:

If i is recurrent, then the return time is also finite, but nonetheless the mean could be
infinite.

I don't understand how this can be true!

Could anyone explain this please? The quote is from p53 Section 5.10 of https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/33251

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ take the values $2^{1},2^{2},2^{3}...$ with probabilites $\frac 1 2, \frac 1{2^{2}}, \frac 1{2^{3}},...$ Then $X$ is a finite random variable: its values are all finite numbers . But its expectation is $\sum 2^{n} \frac 1{2^{n}}=\infty$. So there is no contradcition in a random variable taking finite values (**not finite number of values**) but having infinite mean.